# Strange servlet response issue

Tags: java, servlets, download, response

I have a servlet witch is generating a `.xls` file and then it's sending the generated file to the user for download with the code below:

```
// Write the output to a file
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MMM_dd");
String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());

String path = "webapps/myapp/exports/";
String fileName = ("Table_export_"+ dateNow + ".xls");

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path+fileName);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
```

The file is saved on the server with a size of 5 kb, but after the browser dialog and after choosing save or open, the file is empty and the size is 0 kb. I can not understand what is wrong.

I'm fighting with this issue for about 2 hours without a success. I have tried to set the full path:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="path+fileName);
```

But I got a document with a strange name and it also was 0 kb.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something really small, but as a junior developer I still can not figure it out.

Comment: Are you trying to send the file in the HTTP response or what? Sorry I cannot understand your code.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: But you are saving the file in the file system instead! If you want to send file over HTTP you have to write bytes into `OutputStream` the you get from HTTP response.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way to return the file saved on the local server disk?

Comment: What AxelR said is right, you need to put the file (indeed, you have to put the CONTENT of the file) in the response in some way.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with the file in the client? is this a browser, is this a client application?

Comment: Do you need to send the file AND store it on your server? If you only need to send it, replace your `FileOutputStream` by `response.getOutputStream()` (but send the headers first).

Comment: It is a browser application running on tomcat6. I'm generating a xls file and saving it on the server HDD in the servlet. As I understand I have to write the content to bytes insted on the disk.

Comment: @Raphaël I just need to send it.

Comment: I think you need to set the content-length header with the size of file, also try to set the header files before you sending something, I mean put the wb.write(fileOut); at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a method that can write your file to an output stream you can simply change your code this way to send it to the user :

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MMM_dd");
String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());

String fileName = ("Table_export_"+ dateNow + ".xls");

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);

OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
try {
    wb.write(outputStream);
} finally {
    outputStream.close();
}
```

It won't be saved on your server HDD though.

The method `HttpServletResponse#getOutputStream()` allows you to access the stream of bytes that will be sent back to the client.

Comment: THANK YOU so mutch!!! This is exacly what I was looking for! You rock! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you used the format -

```
String path = "webapps/myapp/exports/";
String fileName = ("Table_export_"+ dateNow + ".xls");
...
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="path+fileName);
```

Was the filename "webapps%2Fmyapps%2Fexports%2fTable_export_....xls"?

Als the filesize would have been zero because you are not putting any data in the file